# Forest change tutorial results don't make sense compared to area of the country

Tags: google-earth-engine, area

I've been following this Earth Engine tutorial on calculating forest loss by country, and running that same code for multiple other countries. What I had matched the expected output that the tutorial references (ie. 348,036,295 square meters of forest lost in Congo in 2012).

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_forest_03

I was curious what tree cover lost each year was as a percentage of total land area in each country, but those results don't make any sense. For Congo, there are years when 20-50% of the total country area show forest loss. When I tried this with other countries, the results are worse--with forest loss sometimes over 100% of the country's land area.

I'm getting the country's land area from CIA World Factbook: https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/cg.html

Obviously I'm overlooking something very basic?

My code:

```
var country = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2013")
        .filterMetadata('cc', 'equals', 'CF');

// Get the forest loss image.
var hansen = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2018_v1_6')

// separating out the bands
var treecover2000 = hansen.select('treecover2000');
var loss = clipped.select('loss');
var lossAreaImage = loss.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// PRINT YEARLY LOSS BY COUNTRY (SMALL)
var lossyear = hansen.select(['lossyear'])

var lossByYear = lossAreaImage.addBands(lossyear).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
    groupField: 1
    }),
  geometry: country,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
print(lossByYear);

var statsFormatted = ee.List(lossByYear.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el) {
    var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
    return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), d.get('sum')];
  });
var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());

print(statsDictionary);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the country area from the geometry itself, then use that to calculate share

Try this:

```
// Load country
var country = ee.FeatureCollection("USDOS/LSIB/2013")
    .filterMetadata('cc', 'equals', 'CD');


// Get the forest loss image.
var hansen = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2018_v1_6')

// separating out the bands
var treecover2000 = hansen.select('treecover2000');
var loss = hansen.select(['loss']);
var lossAreaImage = loss.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea());

// PRINT YEARLY LOSS BY COUNTRY (SMALL)
var lossyear = hansen.select(['lossyear'])

var lossByYear = lossAreaImage.addBands(lossyear).reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group({
  groupField: 1
    }),
  geometry: country,
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});

var statsFormatted = ee.List(lossByYear.get('groups'))
  .map(function(el) {
  var d = ee.Dictionary(el);
  return [ee.Number(d.get('group')).format("20%02d"), d.get('sum')];
});

var statsDictionary = ee.Dictionary(statsFormatted.flatten());

// Calculate are of country geometry
var area = country.geometry().area()

// Calculate forest loss share of total area
var lossShare = statsDictionary.map(function(k,el) {
  return ee.Number(el).divide(area).multiply(100)
})

print(lossShare)
```

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, I was just making a simple mistake in converting square km to square meters (multiplying by 1000 instead of 1,000,000) when calculating percents.